# CCurl does POW via GPU?

Tags: pow

I develop a simple Node-App and I use ccurl.interface.js and the Windows ccurl.dll from the IOTA-github-site.
I did override the function iota.api.attachToTangle so that the ccurl.dll is used.
I noticed when iota.api.sendTransfer is executed, that the POW is done via my **GPU** (Intel HD Graphics).

When I transfer 0 IOTA it works well.
The problem is, when I transfer more than 0 IOTA, the transaction will be added to the tangle but is invalid.

When using the light wallet I have to choose ccurl (WebGL is not working), and it uses only the **CPU**. 
Is it possible to tell the ccurl.dll, that it has to use CPU only?